# could resolve binding for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/ NO SPRING

Tags: soap, cxf

I have written a small maven project with cxf dependencies that can be run with eclipse (Run as Java Application).
I then use the maven-shade-plugin to create an executable jar.
When I then run the jar from the command line, I get the follwing exception:

```
 javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
```

I have to point out that I'm using Spring. I have come accross a couple of suggestions with for Spring advising to put some cxf xml files into the MeTA-INF directory.
The cxf dependencies that I'am using are as foolows:

```
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
cxf-rt-transports-http
cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty
```

all in the version 3.0.1

I would really appreciate any clues.
Thanks.

Edmond

Comment: cxf-beans.xml please.....

Comment: That is the point. I have no cxf-beans.xml, and I don't know whether I need one or not. As a matter of fact, Eclipse does run the application without extra configuration files

Comment: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/bundling-cxf-into-single-jar-with-maven-shade-plugin.html